# Uncaught ReferenceError: dropdownFunc is not defined. Onclick function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a Django (python) developer trying to do some frontend stuff for the first time.

Frontend script

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
function dropdownFunc(val){
    console.log(val.includes("NoneOfThese_"))
if (val.includes("NoneOfThese_")) {
    $("#dropdown-list_" + val).show();
    }
else {
    $("#dropdown-list_" + val).hide();
    }
}
</script>
```

dropdown-list div:

```
        <div id = "dropdown-list_{{phone_array.count}}" class="jumbotron" style="display:none"> 
            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'insertPhoneDetails' %}">
                 <label for="brandName">Brand name:</label><br>
                 <input type="text" id="brandName" name="brandName"><br>

                 <label for="mobileName">Mobile name:</label><br>
                 <input type="text" id="mobileName" name="mobileName"><br>
</form>
</div>
```

Error on line 32: `<input type="radio" name="options" value="{{key}}" id="dropdown" onclick="dropdownFunc(value)" required> {{value}} <br><br>`

Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: dropdownFunc is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):32)
```

How to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a single script tag that both has a `src` *and* contains inline text. Separate them out into two separate script tags instead:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function dropdownFunc(val){
  // ...
</script>
```

But you also aren't passing the value to `dropdownFunc` correctly, and you should also consider [avoiding inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045), since they have horrible scoping rules and escaping issues. Attach the event listener properly using JavaScript instead, eg:

```
$('#dropdown').on('click', e => dropdownFunc(e.target.value));
```